# First CSS style will not respond to HTML

Tags: css, html

First website, and I can't figure out why my first CSS style block won't work with my HTML compiler.

No matter which style I put up first (by reordering the classes) the one on top won't work.
When "header" was on top, I lost all style for the header text.
When "nav" was on top, I lost all nav style. Etc.

```
<style>
#something {
}
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    }
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}
#section {
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 

}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px; 
}

</style>
```

So, I put in the style "something" in order to make it the class that doesn't work.

There has to be a reason for this though, and a better solution.

Edit: Here's the HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "My First">
<html>
<body>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style2.css" >
</head>

<div id="header">
<h1>Launch</h1>

</div>

<div id="nav">
 <li><a href="othersite.html">Home page</a> <br>
  <li><a href="webdev.html">Latest Post</a> <br>
  <li><a href="town.html">Web Dev</a> <br>
  <li><a href="links.html">Copy Write</a> <br>
  <li><a href="links.html">Old Posts</a>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h1>Launch</h1>

<p>Content...</p>
<p>Content...</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
December 23rd,
    my name
</div>
```

My `<style>` tags were the issue. Still not sure why it caused THAT problem- which seems odd.
I removed the `<style>` tags, and it is working fine.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What is the HTML to go with the styles?

Comment: Can u share u the html sample

Comment: I have very little knowledge of terminology, and am generally clueless- this is my first day with HTML and CSS.

Comment: all the css styles in your post are in style2.css ?

Comment: You should not have `<style>` tag in your `style2.css` just the CSS declarations like `#something{color :red;}`

Comment: Remove background color all classes or  text color white will get the idea else why r u using style tag in css filw

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you have many errors in your HTML. For starters, DOCTYPE declarations don't work like that. Run your source through a validator.

Comment: That DOCTYPE declaration is copied from one of the many HTML tutorials I've been going through. I don't know what it means, but I have no problem running the code on my browser. What is a validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<style>` tag is to be used inside the `<head>` tag of your `html`, **not inside a CSS file**.

So you either place your CSS inside a `<style>` tag in the `html` or in an external referenced file (css), linked with a `<link>`, in which case it should only contain `CSS`, without any `HTML` tags.

Comment: It doesn't have to in the <head>, you can use style anywhere in the <body>, even right at the end, it will still affect previous elements. This is possible because the rendering happens after the DOM parse, not before.

Comment: A `style` element inside the `body` element violates HTML syntax rules. It's supported by most browsers, but it is still a violation. It has only been officially allowed in HTML 5.

Comment: I know, I should have made this clear, my bad. But it's still good to know in some cases.

Comment: Yes agreed with u.. like it

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you are using `<style>` tag inside the .css file. It's not required when you are using EXTERNAL CSS.

You can only use `<style>` tag inside the HTML and this is called INTERNAL CSS.

Solution is that just remove the `<style>` tag from your .css file.