# Header not changing style using CSS, however other div is

Tags: html, css, raspberry-pi, webserver, apache2

I am trying to get my header background to change color using css, however I am unable to change anything other than the position of my nav `<div>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/70d40nnt/2/

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    background:#7D72F7;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
    float:right;
    padding:5px; 
    text-align:center;
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    padding:10px; 
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: In JSfiddle, you don't need the <Style> and <body> tags. They're automatically added. Is this the only place you're having the issue or is it occurring still on your actual site?

Comment: Yeah, if you remove the `<style>` tags, your code works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First CSS style will not respond to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566107/first-css-style-will-not-respond-to-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<style></style>` from your stylesheet and your jsfiddle works. Indeed, they are needed only for css directives inside a html page.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<style>` tags from the "CSS" box (and `<body>` from the "HTML" one), and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

remove the style tag in css block in js fiddle. JS fiddle doesn't need style tag to be defined. Directly write the styles.